# Creating user with createUserWithEmailAndPassword with admin user logged in changes the current user to the newly created one in firebase

Tags: android, firebase

So, in my android app, I have created an admin user through which I can create new users in firebase. But the problem is whenever I create a new user when the current user is admin user, it automatically changes the current user to the newly created one. It effects when say I exit out of that app and restart again. So, during that time, it always logs in with the new user. **( I have used a logic to stay login to the user even when I restart again. So I won't have to log in again)**.

So, my question is how can I create a new user while admin user is logged in and still retain the current user as the admin user. I have tried to look up in firebase official documentation and some other resources but I can't find a correct solution. Can anyone give me some suggestions? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Every one. This is an old question of mine. I saw that as of the moment that I check this question, it has 41 views and there is no answer provided for this question. So, I thought of answering my own question as others might face the same issue that I had in future.

Actually, I was able to fix the issue with a little trick. What I did was as soon as the admin user creates the new user and the new user authenticates automatically, I just signout that user using

> mAuth.signOut();

After that I call `signInWithEmailAndPassword` passing the email and password of the admin user as the parameter in the method. Then, this keeps me logged in to admin user, even when I relaunched the app. I know this might not be the best way to do it. But it worked for me. If there is some better way to do it, please do let me know. I am open to knowledge and learning. :)

```
//create user
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(NewStudentActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
      // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
      // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
      // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
      if (task.isSuccessful()) {
          Toast.makeText(NewStudentActivity.this, "User added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          mAuth.signOut();                          
          mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("admin_email@gmail.com", "admin_password").addOnCompleteListener(NewStudentActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
   @Override
   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
      //admin sign in again

      }
  });
  } else {
    Toast.makeText(NewStudentActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
     }
});
```

**Note:** This is a temporary solution which I implemented for a college project. There is lot of security flaws with this solution. In no way, this can be said as a good solution for a full-fledge project.

Comment: That's a very bad way of implementation though it provides a temporary solution, it is having a functional and security loophole, wherein you have hardcoded emailid and password which is a security threat and what if there are multiple admins, thats gonna cause functional threat. What I would suggest is to make use of Google Cloud function and create a http request to pass data and create a user within the function. That's the way more better approach with protected security and functionals flaws. :)

Comment: Hi, @GuruprasadRao thnks for the input. Actually, this is a very old answer of mine and the project which I was working then was a college project. I didn't know about Google cloud then and had a very limited knowledge about firebase. This is definitely not a solid solution and there was no proper firebase way to do it then. But I think there has been a lot of changes in firebase itself now and as you said even one can use Google cloud like services. Thanks again. i will keep a note that this is a temporary solution and for a college project. :)

Comment: :) Happy coding.. :)